# Anime where the main character was an illusion or something, made by his older self

Tags: story-identification, anime

There were also girls with invisible swords that were only able to be seen by the protagonist. One of them had something like a Stand from *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure*.

The main character was weak up until the end, when he manifested his sword. I remember a scene where he was maybe dying, and asked if the one girl he was looking at was an angel. It was on Netflix years ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ***[ChäoS;HEAd](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1278254/)*** (2008).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos;Head_(TV_series)):

> Chaos;Head follows Takumi Nishijo, a high school student living in a cargo crate atop a building in Shibuya, Tokyo. One day, he is sent pictures over the internet, depicting a murder in an alley; he later witnesses a murder resembling the one in the pictures, and believes the killer to be a pink-haired girl he sees at the crime scene. Because of his presence at the scene of the crime, he is suspected of being the murderer, and develops paranoia and experiencing delusions. More murders – referred to as the New Generation serial murders – occur, while Takumi meets a number of girls who have an interest in him, but who he suspects of being linked to the murders. One of them is the pink-haired girl, named Rimi, who claims to be friends with him despite him not having any previous memory of her.
>
> **Takumi learns of the existence of people called "gigalomaniacs", who can use special powers to project delusions onto others' minds; they can also project delusions into reality, which is referred to as "real-booting". Takumi and several of the girls he met are revealed to be such individuals, and can use illusory "Di-Sword" weapons projected into reality.** The Nozomi Group in Shibuya is revealed to have created a synthetic gigalomaniac machine called the Noah II, which they use for their own gain, causing people to panic from experiencing delusions. **Takumi learns that he is an artificial delusional clone with fabricated memories, created by the real Takumi to stop the Nozomi Group from taking over humanity. He did this as his body had been aged from overuse of gigalomaniac powers, hindering him from stopping the Nozomi Group personally.** Takumi reveals the nurse Hazuki as the criminal behind the murders by projecting her memories onto screens on buildings, and destroys the Noah II and Nozomi's president with his Di-Sword. The real Takumi dies, leaving Takumi to take his place and keep on living.

The bolded sections of the plot summary above seem to match your description, and schoolgirls wielding translucent swords are visible at around the [0:50](https://youtu.be/YewO8J1eb1E?t=50) mark in the video below.

Comment: Thank you for the life of me I couldn't remember this